# Is this a valid Method? Eclipse seems to suggest there is ab issue with my code..I just do not see it

Tags: java

I have no idea why the following code is deemed wrong by eclpise.  I keep getting a red underline below "hasPassed()" ....and I've been staring at the code for a couple of hours...

```
 public String hasPassed()
{
    if (totalMark ==100 && totalMark > passMark)
        return "Pass";

        else if (totalMark != 100)
            return "There is an error with the mark allocation";
}
```

Comment: You need an extra `return`

Comment: If none of those are true, it doesn't return anything. One should be, but there has to be a return statement not in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an extra return, What happen if that 2 conditions are false?

```
 public String hasPassed()
{
    if (totalMark ==100 && totalMark > passMark)
        return "Pass";

        else if (totalMark != 100)
            return "There is an error with the mark allocation";

     return "What i have to return"?
}
```

IMO in this case is more readable refactoring your method but this is personally. Something like this.

```
public String hasPassed(){

  String toReturn = null;

  if (totalMark ==100 && totalMark > passMark){
          toReturn="Pass";
  }else if (totalMark != 100){
          toReturn= "There is an error with the mark allocation";
  }
     return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: @user3013144 consider accepting the answer and upvoting those that help you answering!

Answer (score 0):

As in the if there is still the possibility of any of the conditions being met will may end up with no valid return at all.

Try the below:

```
  public String hasPassed()
  {
    if (totalMark == 100 && totalMark > passMark)
    {
      return "Pass";
    }
    else if (totalMark != 100)
    {
      return "There is an error with the mark allocation";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

It's also a good practice to always use the braces in the ifs for code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is why it's a good idea to always put a single return at the end of the method.

```
public String hasPassed()
{
  String message = "Default message";

  if (totalMark ==100 && totalMark > passMark)
  {
    message = "Pass";
  } else if (totalMark != 100)
  {
        message = "There is an error with the mark allocation";
  }

  return message;
}
```